# What is the meaning of "bucket on the head" in this context?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, expressions

What is the meaning of "bucket on the head" in this context?

> Patulous Eustachian tube […] is a physical disorder where the Eustachian
>   tube, which is normally closed, instead stays intermittently open.
>   When this occurs, the patient experiences autophony, the hearing of
>   self-generated sounds. These sounds, such as one's own breathing,
>   voice, and heartbeat, vibrate directly onto the ear drum and can
>   create a **"bucket on the head"** effect.

<sub>([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patulous_Eustachian_tube))</sub>

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a link to your source.

Comment: The sounds you would hear if you put a bucket over your head... You would hear the internalized sounds mentioned in the quote.

Comment: (http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://fitnowtraining.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/bucket_head1.jpg&imgrefurl=http://fitnowtraining.com/2010/12/lack-of-time-is-a-lame-excuse/&h=402&w=242&tbnid=d3xb_NnSDBv4SM:&zoom=1&docid=BH5YQHISpe-KwM&ei=A4diVd-yFbWAsQTPp4HABQ&tbm=isch&ved=0CB4QMygBMAE)

Comment: "Head in a bucket" might make a little more sense, but "on" is used because the bottom of the bucket will be on your head (think in the same manner as you wear a cap or helmet *on* your head).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, "**Bucket on the head**" is not an idiom or an expression used in English. I think the phrase *"Bucket on the head"* is used *literally* here. What happens when you put your head in a bucket and stand still? You can hear yourself breathe. The echoes of your respiration will be caught by your ear drums. You can hear every *'sigh'* and *'gulp'*, in a magnified intensity. These are things you generally don't hear (or notice). But when your head is in a bucket, the closure of the bucket helps you hear every single breath, every heartbeat.

Since the context talks about the same things I've mentioned, I don't think "**bucket on the head**" has any other meaning here.